# Tomcat installation in Eclipse Oxygen release (4.7.0)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to start Tomcat server in my Eclipse Oxygen release 4.7.0 but getting this error:

```
Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase 
startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start 
component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container 
failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is 
unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to 
start component [StandardServer[8005]] at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start 
component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService 
stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 25, 2017 2:09:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Tomcat is working fine if i start it by running catalina.sh from the apache tomcat folder in the terminal, but while trying to start it with eclipse it's giving these above errors.

Can anyone please explain what is this error and how to resolve this issue? 
P.S. I am a new-bee to java.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this complete? I'm looking at 'caused by' with main exception. Usually tomcat exceptions are clear (more or less :) )

Comment: i forgot to add some info.Now i have added:).@JacekCz

Comment: Can you share your `server.xml` ?